# sequelize belongsToMany foreignKey attribute not woking

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a three tables users, messages and message_recipients. The table message_recipients is the table that creates mapping between messages and users table. This table has two columns, one is recipient_id that points to corresponding user from users table and the other is message_id that points to corresponding message in the messages table.

Now this is how I am defining the associations.

```
Message.hasMany(MessageRecipient, {as: {singular: 'recipient', plural: 'recipients'}, foreignKey: 'message_id', targetKey: 'id'});
Message.belongsToMany(User, {as: {singular: 'recipient', plural: 'recipients'}, through: MessageRecipient, foreignKey: 'recipient_id'});

MessageRecipient.belongsTo(Message, {as: 'message', foreignKey: 'message_id', targetKey: 'id'});
MessageRecipient.belongsTo(User, {as: 'recipient', foreignKey: 'recipient_id', targetKey: 'id'});
```

Now If include `recipients` while fetching the messages I get an error that says

`unknown column user_id in message_recipients columns.`

There is a similar [question](http://Message.hasMany(MessageRecipient,%20%7Bas:%20%7Bsingular:%20'recipient',%20plural:%20'recipients'%7D,%20foreignKey:%20'message_id',%20targetKey:%20'id'%7D);%20Message.belongsToMany(User,%20%7Bas:%20%7Bsingular:%20'recipient',%20plural:%20'recipients',%20foreignKey:%20'recipient_id'%7D,%20through:%20MessageRecipient%7D);%20%20MessageRecipient.belongsTo(Message,%20%7Bas:%20'message',%20foreignKey:%20'message_id',%20targetKey:%20'id'%7D);%20MessageRecipient.belongsTo(User,%20%7Bas:%20'recipient',%20foreignKey:%20'recipient_id',%20targetKey:%20'id'%7D);) asked already. and an answer to it suggests defining the references. But after defining the references I am getting the same error.

**Update**

I decided to rename the column name from recipient_id to user_id. Because the sequelize was looking for column user_id in messages_recipients table.

But after renaming column recipient_id to user_id it starts looking for column recipient_id and the error message changes to

`unknown column recipient_id in table message_recipients`

Answer (score 3):

This part of Sequelizer is powerful but confusing.

Assuming that you are trying to link message.id to message_recipient.message_id AND message_recipient.user_id to user_id, try this:

```
Message.hasMany(MessageRecipient, 
    {sourceKey : 'id',          // message table
    foreignKey: 'message_id'}   // recipient table
    );

MessageRecipient.belongsTo(User,  
    {foreignKey : 'user_id',    // recipient
    otherKey: 'id'              // user
    });

Message.belongsToMany(User, {through: MessageRecipient, 
    foreignKey: 'message_id',   // recipient
    otherKey : 'user_id'     // recipient.
    });


Message.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'message_body'],
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            attributes: [
                ['id','recipient_id'],
                ['username','recipient_name']
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

This produced a list of messages, each containing a sub-list of recipients.  Likely, the code is not as tight as could be...